# Polymer async not working in FireFox

Tags: ajax, firefox, asynchronous, polymer

Has anyone run into problems with polymer's 'async' call in FireFox?  My site is working well in the latest version of Chrome, but not so much luck in FireFox.  One of the first things the site endeavors to do is to retrieve some object collections from a database (via core-ajax / REST API).  Immediately after calling the functions required to retrieve the collections, I make a call to a function that asynchronously populates local storage variables with the resulting collections from the various datasource elements that make the ajax calls and handle the responses.  FireFox is calling the `populateLocalStorage` function specified as an argument to the `async` call, but unlike in Chrome, the call is occurring before the datasource elements have received their ajax responses and handled them accordingly.  Therefore, '_bugs' and '_snakes' (in this example), end up as undefined.  Here is the script excerpt from the polymer element in question:

```
<script>

    Polymer('my-app-index', {

        bugs: null,
        snakes: null,
        spiders: null,

        ready: function () {                
            this.retrieveCollections();
        },

        retrieveCollections: function() {
            // custom datasource elements that make necessary ajax call(s) 
            // (using core-ajax), and handle ajax responses appropriately
            // This element accesses the resulting collections via 2 way databinding 
            // to the datasource(s) element attributes
            this.$.bugsDS.getAll(); 
            this.$.snakesDS.getAll();
            this.$.spidersDS.getAll();

            this.async(this.populateLocalStorage); // Populate local storage with resulting collections
        },

        populateLocalStorage: function () {
            mynamespace._bugs = this.bugs;
            mynamespace._snakes = this.snakes;
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Definitely need some feedback on this one.  Am I doing something incorrectly?  Can anyone reproduce this same problem, if at least  to confirm that I'm not crazy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each `getAll()` performs an async ajax request, it's extremely unlikely all won't finish in a single rAF (16.66ms). That's what `this.async()` does. It callback gets called one `requestAnimationFrame` later.

Instead you'll want to react to the arrays changing. Whenever they populate their respective arrays, you can set the local storage:

```
retrieveCollections: function() {
    this.$.bugsDS.getAll(); 
    this.$.snakesDS.getAll();
    this.$.spidersDS.getAll();
},

bugsChanged: function() {
  this.populateLocalStorage('_bugs', this.bugs);
},

snakesChanged: function() {
  this.populateLocalStorage('_snakes', this.snakes);
},

populateLocalStorage: function (key, data) {
  mynamespace[key] = data;
}
```

Alternatively, you could setup an `observe` block and handle both properties changing with a single function:

```
observe: {
  'bugs snakes': 'populateLocalStorage'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the async call.  It also must be  that different browsers handle async (or perhaps requestAnimationFrames) differently, as it was working nicely in Chrome.